# Problema con Funciones Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

¡Hola! Tengo un problema para realizar y no encuentro el modo de solucionarlo, supongo que será más fácil de lo que me está resultando.
me piden esto:

- La función saluda existe (ESTO ESTÁ OK)
- La función saluda funciona correctamente (me da mal)
- La variable mensajeSaludo es el resultado de invocar a saluda con el string "Upgrade" (me da mal)
- La función sumaTextos existe (ESTO ESTÁ OK)
- La función sumaTextos funciona correctamente‣ (me da mal)
- La variable textoFinal es el resultado de invocar a sumaTextos con los argumentos "Estoy sumando" y "dos cadenas de texto"(me da mal)

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
// Crea una función que se llame saluda y que reciba un argumento llamado nombre. Esta función devolverá (hará return) de la suma del string "Te damos al bienvenida, " junto con el argumento nombre.
function saluda (nombre){
  return "Te damos la bienvenida" + saluda;
}

// Crea una variable mensajeSaludo que sea igual a invocar a la función saluda usando como argumento el string "Upgrade".
saluda ("Upgrade");

var mensajeSaludo = saluda ("Upgrade");

// Crea ahora una función que se llame, sumaTextos que reciba dos argumentos, textoA y textoB. Esta función devolverá por medio de return la suma de los dos strings separados por espacios.
function sumaTextos(textoA, textoB) {
  return textoA + textoB
  
}

// Crea una variable textoFinal que sea igual a invocar la función sumaTextos con los argumentos "Estoy sumando" y "dos cadenas de texto".
sumaTextos ("Estoy sumando", "dos cadenas de texto");

var textoFinal= textoA + textoB;
```

Answer (score 1):

En ambos casos, al tratarse de "concatenación" de cadenas, debes quitar la parte `suma =` del `return`.

Además, tienes un error en lo que deseas concatenar en tu función `saluda`, ya que usas `saluda`, cuando deberías usar `nombre`.

La función `saluda` debería verse así:

```js
function saluda(nombre) {
  return "Te damos la bienvenida " + nombre; // quieres concatenar "nombre" y no "saluda"
}
```

Cuando devuelves:

```js
return suma = "Te damos la bienvenida " + saluda;  // devuelve 'undefined'
```

Estás devolviendo el resultado de la concatenación, que en este caso es `undefined`. No es igual que una "suma" porque las cadenas no pueden "sumarse".

En la segunda función tienes el mismo error, y debería ser:

```js
function sumaTextos(textoA, textoB) {
  return textoA + textoB;
}
```

El nombre de la función es bastante desconcertante. Las cadenas o texto no pueden "sumarse", como ya bein he dicho, en cambio, se concatenan.

Por último, si quieres asignar a una variable el resultado de llamar a `sumaTextos` con los argumentos que muestras en tu pregunta, debería ser así:

```js
const textoFinal =  sumaTextos("Estoy sumando", "dos cadenas de texto");
```

Actualmente lo tienes así:

```js
var textoFinal= textoA + textoB;
```

Pero tanto `textoA` como `textoB` sólo existen dentro de la función `sumaTextos`, por lo cual no puedes usarlos fuera de ella.

Si estás siguiendo un curso o tutorial, yo lo cambiaría (es malo IMHO). Si es una clase académica, habría que plantearse si el profesor está realmente poniendo a prueba sus capacidades o es un simple error por descuido.

Comment: Mauricio: una asignación en el return es completamente inofensiva. Inutil pero inofensiva. No da undefined.  `const saluda=(nombre) => suma = 'hola  ' + nombre`

Comment: ¡Hola! Antes que nada, gracias por vuestras respuestas. Efectivamente, a mi lo que es la creación de ambas funciones me salían correctas, es verdad que el suma sobra y es correcto quitarlo. Lo que no me sale es el resto, la declaración de las funciones (me sale que no funciona) y las variables tampoco me salen correctas :(

Comment: Ya lo he modificado. LA cuestión es que no me sale la otra parte del ejercicio, "Crea una variable mensajeSaludo que sea igual a invocar a la función saluda usando como argumento el string "Upgrade"." Es lo que no entiendo muy bien qué tengo qué hacer

Comment: @Carmen lo que te piden con eso, es que la variable mensajeSaludo obtenga el resultado de usar la funcion saluda.

Es decir que el valor que tome mensajeSaludo sea "Te damos la bienvenida Upgrade";

Comment: Al final el error estaba es que estaba mal escrito el texto "Te damos la bienvenida," (no puse la coma), y luego el string espacio + " " + no lo puse tampoco. GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 0):

La consola devuelve:  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: textoA is not defined"

Esto es porque en la ultima linea estas metiendo en una variable textoA y textoB que son variables declaradas dentro de una funcion y solo se pueden utilizar ahí.

Ademas segun el enunciado debías devolver las dos funciones dentro de la variable textoFinal

---